# Processing a file upload with javascript before saving to database in Cakephp

Tags: javascript, ajax, cakephp, file-upload, cakephp-2.1

I have a form that includes a file upload.

I need to extract some meta information using javascript from the file before saving the contents of the form to my database.

What would be the best way, if any, of achieving this?

To clarify: The issue isn't the with extracting the file meta but rather how to access the $_FILES array and execute a js file with this data before finally allowing the form to submit to the server.

How I am achieving this currently:

1. I submit the form to the controller action
2. It saves the data and then it sets a view variable with the location of
   the uploaded file before re-rendering the initial view upon successful form submission
3. The view checks if the variable is set, and if it is, executes the
   javascript which basically extracts the meta now that it can access where the file is, and updates the db
   with an ajax call.

The above method is not ideal in that the meta belongs to the same row of data that is saved when the form first submits so ideally I would like to include it initial form submission and not when the page is rendered again after the form has been submitted. Seems like a bit of a dirty hack to me but I can't as of yet see another way this can be achieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest uploading using ajax (SWFUpload/Uploadify) and then sending data back to the view with the processed file data.

You can upload the file, issue a number of callbacks, and finally return the rendered filedata back to the waiting javascript function that issued the request.

Just my two cents

Answer (score 0):

What sort of metadata?  To answer your question, yes, this is possible, but only if the browser supports the File API.  This excludes IE9 and older.  For more information, see [this MDN article on FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileReader).  There are various libraries that will extract specific types of metadata from files.  For example, if you are interested in parsing EXIF metadata from an image file, you should look into something like [jQuery-fileExif](https://github.com/sanisoft/jQuery-fileExif).

Comment: Sorry, I should be more specific. My issue isn't the js part. I can extract what I need without issue with input I feed the js file. The issue is that I'm uncertain how to achieve this within the process of a form submit. I.e stop the form submission, Grab the tmp_name from the $_FILES array, and then allow the form to submit once the js file extracting the meta has finished executing. Have updated question.